# Extracting all information(different) with same row name form a excel worksheet using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel workheet having a table with multiple rows having same name with different information in the corresponding columns. Now using a formula I want to extract this infomation into a new table? SOLUTION HAS TO BE USING AN EXCEL FOMULA ? NO FILTERS NO PIVOT TABLE OR VBA

I have tried vlookup. to search for multiple values. I dont want information from a single column but rather from all the columns. There could be thousands of columns with same and different values.

I have tried this formula : =INDEX(Worksheet!A2:AK350;KKLEINSTE(WENN((A5=Worksheet!A2:A350);VERGLEICH(ZEILE(Worksheet!A2:A350);ZEILE(Worksheet!A2:A350));"");1))

The table looks like this for example:

> Place  People      Salary    Status
>
> japan | resident_1 | 564    | un-married
>   Delhi | resident_1 | 655     | un-married
>   china | resident_1 | 564    | un-married
>   japan | resident_2 | 748 | un-married
>
> Now I want to extract a sub table from the above, like all the
>   infomation having PLACE name as "japan"
>
> the reult should be this for each place in a different table:
>
> japan | resident_1 | 564    | un-married
>   japan | resident_2 | 748    | un-married

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a job for advanced filter, but you've already stipulated *"no filters"*. If you're able to add two helper columns in your main table, maybe you can use the approach below.

This is my `main_table` worksheet (note the columns outlined in red, which have been added).

[image: main_table worksheet]

- The formula in column `E` (starting from cell `E2`) is: `=CONCAT(A2,"|",B2,"|",C2,"|",D2)`
- The formula in column `F` (starting from cell `F2`) is: `=ROW()-ROW($F$2)+1`
- Drag/fill these formulas down to the last row in your main table.

This is my `sub_table` worksheet (note the cells outlined in green at the top, where you will eventually specify filter criteria).

[image: sub_table worksheet]

- The formula in column `A` (starting from cell `A5`) is: `=ROW()-ROW($A$5)+1`
- The formula in column `B` (starting from cell `B5`) is: `=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$2,main_table!$E$2:$E$10)),main_table!$F$2:$F$10,""),$A5),"")`
- The formula in columns `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` (starting from cell `C5`) is: `=IF(ISNUMBER($B5),INDEX(main_table!$A$2:$D$10,$B5,COLUMNS($C5:C5)),"")`
- The formula in cell `B2` is: `=CONCAT(IF(ISBLANK($C$2),"*",$C$2),"|",IF(ISBLANK($D$2),"*",$D$2),"|",IF(ISBLANK($E$2),"*",$E$2),"|",IF(ISBLANK($F$2),"*",$F$2))`
- You should drag the formula down for the same number of rows that are in your main table.

I think newer/upcoming versions of Excel have a `JOIN` worksheet function which is more convenient/flexible than my usage of `CONCAT` above (so maybe use that if it's available to you).

Leaving the filter criteria blank should give you all rows. If you want partial matches, include wildcards in your input e.g. `jap*` or `resident_*`. If any of the values in your main table contain a `|`, you may want to use a different delimiter in the `CONCAT` formulas (otherwise you may get unexpected results/behaviour).

Once you're done, maybe you can use it like shown below:

[image: Usage]

See if this approach is any good for you (you will probably need to translate the formulas to your locale/region).

Comment: Hallo chilin, thankyou very much for your brief reply. I really appreciate your efforts. But since the data is confidential. I am not allowed to use any helper functions. Sorry.

Comment: and I just want place to be changed and shown the corresponding rows and columns. I can do that with pivot in like 5 minutes. But my collegues want FORMULAAAAAA